# Angular-Highcharts: Chart Pie is not working when change between tabs

Tags: typescript, charts, highcharts, angular9

I tried to implementent Highcharts v8.0.1, in a view with lazy loading in Angular 9 and Angular Material in the tabs. I have two tabs, where the pie chart is in the first tab. So, when the view charge normaly,  it's works fine... but, when i press the second tab and then press the first tab to return, the chart dissapear and only have the indicators. This problems appears only with this chart type and i don't now how can i fix.

Thanks a lot!

zones-pie-chart.component-html

```
<div class="card bg-dark shadow">
  <highcharts-chart
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
    [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
    [options]="chartOptions[0]"
    [callbackFunction]=""
    [(update)]="updateFlag"
    [oneToOne]="oneToOneFlag"
    [runOutsideAngular]="runOutsideAngular"
    style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
  ></highcharts-chart>
</div>
```

zones-pie-chart.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-zones-pie-charts',
  templateUrl: './zones-pie-charts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./zones-pie-charts.component.css']
})
export class ZonesPieChartsComponent {
  // HIGHCHARTS
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts; // required
  chartConstructor = 'chart'; // optional string, defaults to 'chart'
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options[] = []; // required
  updateFlag = false; // optional boolean
  oneToOneFlag = true; // optional boolean, defaults to false
  runOutsideAngular = false; // optional boolean, defaults to false
  options: any = [{
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false,
      type: 'pie'
    },
    credits: {
      enable: false
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Current children by zones'
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    accessibility: {
      point: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
          connectorColor: 'silver'
        },
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: '% Public',
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [
        { name: 'Animal 1', y: 4.5 },
        { name: 'Animal 2', y: 5.5 },
        { name: 'Animal 3', y: 11.8 },
        { name: 'Animal 4', y: 12.3 },
        { name: 'Animal 5', y: 1.2 },
        { name: 'Animal 6', y: 8.7 },
        { name: 'Animal 7', y: 9.3 },
        { name: 'Animal 8', y: 15.4 },
        { name: 'Animal 9', y: 10.3 },
        { name: 'Animal 10', y: 20,
          sliced: true, selected: true}
        ]
    }]
  }];

  constructor( ) {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      chart: {
        style: {
          fontFamily: '"Open Sans", sans-serif',
          stroke: 0,
        },
        backgroundColor: '#2d353c'
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      },
      lang: {
        downloadCSV: 'Exportar en CSV',
        downloadJPEG: 'Exportar en JPEG',
        downloadPDF: 'Exportar en PDF',
        downloadPNG: 'Exportar en PNG',
        downloadSVG: 'Exportar en SVG',
        downloadXLS: 'Exportar en XLS',
        printChart: 'Imprimir gráfico',
        noData: 'No hay datos para visualizar'
      },
      title: {
        style: {
          textTransform: 'camelcase',
        }
      },
      subtitle: {
        style: {
          textTransform: 'camelcase',
        }
      },
      colors: Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
        return {
          radialGradient: {
            cx: 0.5,
            cy: 0.3,
            r: 0.7
          },
          stops: [
            [0, color],
            [1, Highcharts.color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
          ],
        };
      })
    });
    this.chartOptions.push(this.options[0]);
  }
}
```

zones.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ZonesRoutingModule } from './zones-routing.module';
import {PeopleIndicatorChartComponent} from '../../../components/people-indicator-chart/people-indicator-chart.component';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HighchartsChartModule} from 'highcharts-angular';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {ZonesComponent} from './zones.component';
import {ZonesPublicResumeComponent} from '../../../components/zones-public-resume/zones-public-resume.component';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {ZonesPieChartsComponent} from '../../../components/zones-pie-charts/zones-pie-charts.component';
import {ZoneSummaryTableComponent} from '../../../components/zone-summary-table/zone-summary-table.component';
import {FlexModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {ZoneAnimalResumeComponent} from '../../../components/zone-animal-resume/zone-animal-resume.component';
import {PeopleCardModule} from '../../../components/people-card/people-card.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ZonesComponent,
    PeopleIndicatorChartComponent,
    ZonesPublicResumeComponent,
    ZonesPieChartsComponent,
    ZoneSummaryTableComponent,
    ZoneAnimalResumeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ZonesRoutingModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    FormsModule,
    HighchartsChartModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    FlexModule,
    PeopleCardModule,
    MatIconModule,
  ]
})
export class ZonesModule { }
```

PS: It is my first question on the platform, try not to crucify me (!Ja). Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Thank you for your code, but you mentioned that the issue occurs when you are switching the tabs. Are you able to reproduce this behaviour on some online editor which I could work on? Here is a template which you can start from: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-go8sk

Comment: what is highcharts-chart tag?

Comment: The tag <highcharts-chart> is a component selector and according a official documentation, this is the way to declare in the view. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Now i make a replic to my view in a sandbox (Thanks @SebastianWędzel), so maybe for the next few hours i have an example of the error. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems that the problem is this:

```
colors: Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
    return {
      radialGradient: {
        cx: 0.5,
        cy: 0.3,
        r: 0.7
      },
      stops: [
        [0, color],
        [1, Highcharts.color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
      ],
    };
  })
});
```

For some reason Highchart doesnt support gradient colors in his options and you are setting this options globally, so all the charts that will be using those colors, will not charge. The solution is define the original colors of Highchart in a variable (like originalColors) at the beginning of your component and in an ngOnDestroy, return the original colors with "Highcharts.getOptions().colors = originalColors;", like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-zones-pie-charts',
  templateUrl: './zones-pie-charts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./zones-pie-charts.component.css']
})
export class ZonesPieChartsComponent implements OnDestroy { // Dont forget to implement OnDestroy
  // HIGHCHARTS
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts; // required
  chartConstructor = 'chart'; // optional string, defaults to 'chart'
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options[] = []; // required
  updateFlag = false; // optional boolean
  oneToOneFlag = true; // optional boolean, defaults to false
  runOutsideAngular = false; // optional boolean, defaults to false
  // FIX
  originalColors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
  //
    options: any = [{
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false,
      type: 'pie'
    },
    credits: {
      enable: false
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Current children by zones'
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    accessibility: {
      point: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
          connectorColor: 'silver'
        },
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: '% Public',
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [
        { name: 'Animal 1', y: 4.5 },
        { name: 'Animal 2', y: 5.5 },
        { name: 'Animal 3', y: 11.8 },
        { name: 'Animal 4', y: 12.3 },
        { name: 'Animal 5', y: 1.2 },
        { name: 'Animal 6', y: 8.7 },
        { name: 'Animal 7', y: 9.3 },
        { name: 'Animal 8', y: 15.4 },
        { name: 'Animal 9', y: 10.3 },
        { name: 'Animal 10', y: 20,
          sliced: true, selected: true}
        ]
    }]
  }];

  constructor( ) {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      chart: {
        style: {
          fontFamily: '"Open Sans", sans-serif',
          stroke: 0,
        },
        backgroundColor: '#2d353c'
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      },
      lang: {
        downloadCSV: 'Exportar en CSV',
        downloadJPEG: 'Exportar en JPEG',
        downloadPDF: 'Exportar en PDF',
        downloadPNG: 'Exportar en PNG',
        downloadSVG: 'Exportar en SVG',
        downloadXLS: 'Exportar en XLS',
        printChart: 'Imprimir gráfico',
        noData: 'No hay datos para visualizar'
      },
      title: {
        style: {
          textTransform: 'camelcase',
        }
      },
      subtitle: {
        style: {
          textTransform: 'camelcase',
        }
      },
      colors: Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
        return {
          radialGradient: {
            cx: 0.5,
            cy: 0.3,
            r: 0.7
          },
          stops: [
            [0, color],
            [1, Highcharts.color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
          ],
        };
      })
    });
    this.chartOptions.push(this.options[0]);
  }
  // FIX
  ngOnDestroy() {
   Highcharts.getOptions().colors = originalColors;
  }
 //
}
```

Fix thanks to this posts:
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=37824
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=36459

---

**Previous Answer**

Thanks for sharing this, i think it would be usefull to specify if you are using the material tabs with the lazy loading implementation or just the normal one.

Lazy Loading:

```
<mat-tab-group >
  <mat-tab label="tab1" >
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      content
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="tab2">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      content
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Normal:

```
<mat-tab-group >
   <mat-tab label="tab1" >
        content
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="tab2">
        content
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I know this is just a workaround but in case that you are using the lazy loading implementation, it may help you to change to the normal one, while you or someone find the solution. Hope this help ;)

Comment: It's working when charge the view in the first try and i can navigate between tabs, but i change the view in the menu, return and i have the same error again. Thanks for the contribution anyway.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by applying the last contribution. Thank you!